# How to name a square matrix with zeros/ones entries?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, matrix-equations

I would like to know is there exist the term for a square matrix like this:
                                                    $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
                                                0&0&0&0&1\\
                                                0&0&0&0&1\\
                                                0&0&0&0&1\\
                                                0&0&0&0&1\\
                                                0&0&0&0&1
                                                \end{array}\right).
                                                $$
All entries of the matrix $A$ are zero with the exception of the last column where all entries equal are to the unit. Is it possible to write the matrix $A$ more shortly for any size?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but the type of matrix you describe is a subset of the [binary/Boolean matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix).

Comment: usually a matrix with a lot of zeros is called a 'sparse matrix'

Comment: I've never heard of any name that applies to just this kind of matrix. I don't think this kind of matrix is important enough to have its own name.

Comment: @HexaFlexagon, I am using this matrix to study an order and an error of the method for ODE.

Comment: You could get a concise description as $A \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ with $a_{i,j} = \delta_{j,n}$. You could probably also write something like $A = (1, 1, \dots, 1, 1) \cdot (0, 0, \dots, 0, 1)^T$ if you insist on the shortest description.

Comment: Your matrix is: binary (0 and 1), right-stochastic (nonnegative with all rows summing to one) and also rank one. A short notation would be ${\mathbf A}={\mathbf 1}_{5\times 1} \cdot {\mathbf i}_{5,5}^{\rm T}$, using the common notation ${\mathbf 1}_{p \times q}$ for a matrix of ones and ${\mathbf i}_{k,n}$ for the $k$-th column of an $n \times n$ identity matrix. The latter is often also written as ${\mathbf \delta}_{k,n}$ as its a sampled Kronecker $\delta$ function $\delta[m-k], \; m=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: As for what it does, it's a mix of a selection matrix and a replication matrix: it selects the $n$-th element ($n$-th row) and replicates it $n$ times.